# Checkbox and resizing drawable (*.png) in android XML

Tags: android, xml, checkbox

I'm trying to configure checkboxes for my Android application and I have a problem : I configured correctly my checkboxes and they're working quite good but, as the space for them is made with weight, i got a problem for the small screen because the image is always the same (and for small screen, it's too large). I just like to know how to link the size of my picture with the dimens.xml in order to get something nice :p
There is this question on Starkoverflow but just an answer which doesn't work because @drawable/... doesn't work with the attributes width and height.

If you want, here is the code :

*DRAWABLE* @Drawable/facebook

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
       <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/fck_inactive" />
       <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/fck_active" />
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/fck_inactive" /> 
    </selector>
```

*XML FILE* part of layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:background="@drawable/white_rectangle">
        <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/facebook"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:button="@drawable/facebook" />
```

Comment: Add different version in your images into a drawable folders

Comment: Did you try to use the proporty android:scaletype for your CheckBox? If thats not an option, you can create seperated folders for different images sizes. That way the @drawable/fck_inactive and @drawable/fck_active can be saved in folders named like "drawable-xdpi". The smartphone will automaticly take the image from the folder, that has the best fitting size/resolution.

Comment: Yeah thanks to both of them, that's what i'll do ! I was just looking for something cleaner and lighter ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand this correctly, you would like to have the background drawable of your checkbox scale correctly with the actual checkbox size.

My solution would be to set the `android:button` field to null and to set the checkbox states as the `android:background` field of the checkbox.

Your code would then become:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/facebook"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:button="@null"
    android:background="@drawable/facebook" />
```

Does that do the trick?